# Setting properties for Shiro in Guice

Tags: shiro

I am trying to change the cookie name and the timeout for my web realm.

Here is my realm:-

```
public class TTShiroWebModule extends ShiroWebModule
{
    public TTShiroWebModule(ServletContext inServletContext)
    {
        super(inServletContext);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void configureShiroWeb()
    {
        bind(CacheManager.class).to(MemoryConstrainedCacheManager.class);
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("sessionManager.cookie.name")).to("SECURITYSESSIONID");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout")).to(3600000);
        expose(CacheManager.class);
        expose(WebSecurityManager.class);

        addFilterChain("/login/*", ANON);
        addFilterChain("/markup/*", USER, NO_SESSION_CREATION);

        bindRealm().to(TestRealm.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindSessionManager(AnnotatedBindingBuilder<SessionManager> inBind)
    {
        inBind.to(DefaultWebSessionManager.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

Looking at the response that comes back, it looks like we are still using JSESSIONID.  What am I doing wrong?

I have tried putting the bindConstant before installing TTShiroWebModule. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my bindSessionManager method to look like this:-

```
@Override
protected void bindSessionManager(AnnotatedBindingBuilder<SessionManager> inBind)
{
    inBind.to(DefaultWebSessionManager.class).asEagerSingleton();
}
```

Looking at the code, I don't think there is a nicer way.  It is unfortunately that the setter methods are not marked with an @Inject :(